# iMacros: URL GOTO={{!COLn}} Error

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I have an eight-column csv ('UTF-8, with BOM' formatted), where the eighth column is a URL. I have the following code that's simple enough and supposed to take me to a different URL pending the row:

```
VERSION BUILD=123456 RECORDER=FX    
SET !DATASOURCE /Users/Ryan/iMacros/test.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 8
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB T=1
URL GOTO={{!COL8}}
```

There's more to it than that, but I essentially just need the URL in column 8 to populate before the rest of the code. Anybody know why I'm getting a crazy error message?

> Error loading page http://api.mybrowserbar.com/cgi/searchp ...
>   google.com/, line 7 (Error code: -933)

Seems like the "https://www.google.com/" at the end of the error message is just whichever website I was currently on while trying to run the macro; the test URL currently in column 8, row 2 is http://www.facebook.com, which appears nowhere in the error. And "Error code: -933" means "Network error while file or page loading." Any ideas? I'm using the newest version of iMacros and Firefox on Mac OS X.

Comment: I also attempted this on iMacros for Chrome and I got a similar error, though it was missing the api.mybrowser stuff and had this: `RuntimeError: Navigation error occured while loading url http://undefined/, details: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, line: 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was simple. Instead of loading your URLs in the csv as http://www.google.com, for example, just load them in as ="http://www.google.com" and it works great.